# Best workflow for inserting an additional step into an animated tikz picture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, overlays, workflow

I have some old beamer slides that contain an animated tikz picture with a bunch of `\only<4->{}` commands and the like. It's a fairly complicated picture with many slides and illustrations. Now I'd like to insert an additional slide immediately before step `i`.

What would you suggest as the best workflow for this?

Essentially, what I want is to add `+1` to all overlays that involve slides above `i`, but not those before. If an overlay starts before `i` and ends on or after `i`, I want to keep its start unchanged and add `+1` to its end slide.

Here is a MWE. The first frame shows a simple animation, and the second one inserts one more step just before step 2.

```
    \documentclass[]{beamer}
    
    \usepackage{tikz}
    
    \begin{document}
    
    %from this:
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{before}
        \begin{center}  
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[arrows=<->] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,6);
        \coordinate (n1) at (8,2);
        \coordinate (n2) at (1,5);
        \coordinate (n3) at (5,4);
        \only<1>{\draw (n1) circle[radius=3pt] node[below left] {$x_1$} ;}
        \only<1-2>{\draw (n2)  circle[radius=3pt] node[below left] {$x_2$};}
        \only<3>{\draw (n3)  circle[radius=3pt] node[below left] {$x_3$};}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    
    %to this:
    \begin{frame}\frametitle{after}
        \begin{center}  
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[arrows=<->] (10,0) -- (0,0) -- (0,6);
        \coordinate (n1) at (8,2);
        \coordinate (n2) at (1,5);
        \coordinate (n3) at (5,4);
        \only<1>{\draw (n1) circle[radius=3pt] node[below left] {$x_1$} ;}
        \only<1-3>{\draw (n2)  circle[radius=3pt] node[below left] {$x_2$};}
        \only<4>{\draw (n3)  circle[radius=3pt] node[below left] {$x_3$};}
        \only<2>{\draw[fill=black] (n1) circle[radius=3pt] ;}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{center}
    \end{frame}
    \end{document}
```